# Are there Sudokus that are so hard that no known logical deduction techniques can reduce it?

Tags: sudoku, solvability

Are there Sudokus that are so hard that no known logical deduction techniques can reduce it? Maybe such a technique would reduce away multiple options?

Comment: https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm?bd=800000000003600000070090200050007000000045700000100030001000068008500010090000400